# Relation between kurtosis and squared second moment

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, physics, statistical-mechanics

> *"The fourth moment is equal to three times the squared second moment."*

$$\langle X^4 \rangle = 3\langle X^2 \rangle^2$$

Is this generally true for any distribution?

I came across this equality while studying [Binder cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binder_parameter) in statistical physics and couldn't find any further explanations in addition to the sentence above.

Comment: That;s true for normal variables with mean zero, but not true in general.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a follow-up: Under which conditions are the fourth moment and the squared second moment the equal? How would the distribution look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: [kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) is not the fourth moment, but the fourth moment divided by the squared second moment (kind of normalization):

$$ \text{Kurt}(X)= \frac{E[(X-\mu)^4]}{(E[(X-\mu)^2])^2}=\frac{m_4}{m_2^2}=\frac{m_4}{\sigma^4}$$

Second: there is also [the excess kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis#Excess_kurtosis), defined as $\kappa'=\text{Kurt}(X)-3$

Your question amounts to ask if $\kappa'=0$ always. The answer is, of course, no.

As the linked Wikipedia article says, the distributions where $\kappa'=0$ are called *mesokurtic*, of which the normal distribution is the main (but not only) example.

But the excess kurtosis can also be negative (eg, exponential distribution) or positive (eg: uniform distribution).